# Find supremum and infimum of the set $\{ x \in \mathbb R : |x| +|x+1|<2 \}. $

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Find supremum and infimum of the set $\{ x \in  \mathbb R : |x| +|x+1|<2 \}. $

Please help someone how can I solve it?

If we take the different cases $(i) x >0, (ii) x<0$ the we are getting some region in $\mathbb R$ but finally will we have to take the union of this solutions or intersection?

Comment: Hint : You can easily plot the function . First , use $(0 , 1)$ and $(-1 , 1)$ points (Because $x = 0$ and $x+1 = 0$) . Between these points function is constant and $x\lt -1 \to f(x) = -2x-1 , x \gt 0 \to f(x) = 2x+1 $ . You can conclude these results only using definition of absolute value function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate three cases: $x\geq 0$, $-1\leq x\leq 0$ and $x\leq -1$

---

The entire set is then the *union* of the three regions. But it's importand that you understand **why** you take the union, don't just memorize you have to take a uniuon:

The point is that separating the cases, you say

- "OK, if $x\geq 0$, then $|x|+|x+1| = 2x+1<2\iff x<\frac12$"
- "And if $-1\leq x\leq 0$, then $|x|+|x+1| = 1 <2$ always"

Now, you know that $x$ is **either** greater than $0$ **OR** it is smaller than $0$. So, the **OR** is what makes you construct a **UNION**, because an element is in a union $A\cup B$ if it is in $A$ **OR** in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: I like to use an array to cut $\mathbb{R}$ in subintervals where
I can remove the absolute values.

$$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \begin{array}{|c|ccc|c|ccc|}\hline x&{-\infty }&&{-1}&&0&&{+\infty }\\
\hline \left|x\right|&&{-x}&&{-x}&&x&\\
\hline \left|x+1\right|&&{-(x+1)}&&x+1&&x+1&\\
\hline \left|x\right|+\left|x+1\right|-2&&&&&&&\\
\hline \end{array}$$

You only need to complete the array's last line and think.